# Convert hexadecimal color to decimal RGB values in UNIX shell script

Tags: shell, hex, decimal, rgb

I'm sure someone has already solved this problem: what is an easy and portable way to convert a hex color value (anything from 000000 to FFFFFF) to 3 decimal values from 0 to 255.  (If you're not familiar with how colors are traditionally represented in HTML, the first two hex digits are the first decimal number, and so forth.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a POSIX compatible version of this script that handles more valid CSS hex color formats (ie: 4-part with alpha channel `#AABBCCDD`, 3 char shortcuts `#FFF`), this should do the trick:

```
#!/bin/sh
##? ~/bin/hex2rgb - convert color hex to rgb
# '#C0FFEE' => 192 255 238
# 'DEADBEEF' => 222 173 190 239
# 'fab' => 255 170 187
__hex2rgb() {
  # reset $1 to scrubbed hex: '#01efa9' becomes '01EFA9'
  set -- "$(echo "$1" | tr -d '#' | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]')"
  START=0
  STR=
  while (( START < ${#1} )); do
    # double each char under len 6 : FAB => FFAABB
    if (( ${#1} < 6 )); then
      STR="$(printf "${1:${START}:1}%.0s" 1 2)"
      (( START += 1 ))
    else
      STR="${1:${START}:2}"
      (( START += 2 ))
    fi
    echo "ibase=16; ${STR}" | bc
  done
  unset START STR
}
__hex2rgb "$@"
```

Comment: Very impressive!

Answer (score 22):

```
$ cat hexrgb.sh
#!/bin/bash
hex="11001A"
printf "%d %d %d\n" 0x${hex:0:2} 0x${hex:2:2} 0x${hex:4:2}

$ ./hexrgb.sh
17 0 26
```

If you are not willing to use bash for substring expansion, I'd still use printf for the conversion.

Comment: More elegant, this.

Answer (score 8):

You can use a script like:

```
#!/bin/sh
# hextorgb.sh
hexinput=`echo $1 | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'`  # uppercase-ing
a=`echo $hexinput | cut -c-2`
b=`echo $hexinput | cut -c3-4`
c=`echo $hexinput | cut -c5-6`

r=`echo "ibase=16; $a" | bc`
g=`echo "ibase=16; $b" | bc`
b=`echo "ibase=16; $c" | bc`

echo $r $g $b
exit 0
```

and use it like:

```
./hextorgb.sh "11001A"
```

resulting in output like:

```
17 0 26
```

It can be improved by testing for arguments and so on, but it does what you want.

Comment: Small note on `bc`; the hex input data *must* be uppercase. Else it'll bite you in the ass down the line when you give it `ff` which is interpreted as the variable ff, which isn't set so it gives you 0.

Comment: thanks, i'll correct that. I only wanted to demonstrate the transformation, script can by improved.

Comment: To get this to work on my machine I had to change `$0` to `$1`

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

hex2rgb() {
    hex=$(echo "${1^^}" | sed 's/#//g')

    a=$(echo $hex | cut -c-2)
    b=$(echo $hex | cut -c3-4)
    c=$(echo $hex | cut -c5-6)

    r=$(echo "ibase=16; $a" | bc)
    g=$(echo "ibase=16; $b" | bc)
    b=$(echo "ibase=16; $c" | bc)

    echo ${1^^}
    echo $r $g $b
}

hex2rgb "#FF0000"
hex2rgb "#00FF00"
hex2rgb "#0000FF"
```

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow, while this may be the correct answer, you should be leaving a little insight/ explanation of what you have done here to make it a quality answer which will help others understand the root cause of problem.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is quite old but to add an anecdote;

alternatively, if you wanted to convert rgb to hex you could do a little something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
# rgbtohex.sh
f="$1,"
focus=0
start=0
until [ "$limit" == "3" ]
  do
    focus=$((focus+1))
    if [ "${f:$focus:1}" == "," ]
    then
        limit=$((limit+1))
        length=$(($focus-$start))
        let c$limit="${f:start:length}"
        start=$((focus+1))
    fi
done
r=`echo "obase=16; $c1" | bc`
r2=`echo "obase=16; $c2" | bc`
r3=`echo "obase=16; $c3" | bc`
if [ "${r:1:2}" == "" ]
  then r=0$r
fi
if [ "${r2:1:2}" == "" ]
  then r2=0$r2
fi
if [ "${r3:1:2}" == "" ]
  then r3=0$r3
fi
echo $r$r2$r3
```